# How can i add links to wpf xmal design by run time code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I can't figure out how the whole thing is built. Do i need to add each link by my self manually ? And if i have 100 links ?

This is a screenshot of what i see in the xmal file

[image: Link]

But maybe i can add this links from the code it self ?
The code is long so i will not add it to here.
I got the project from here:

[Background File Downloader](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35954/C-NET-Background-File-Downloader)

If i want to add to the downloader my own links ?

I see in the DownloaderDemo code this part that add the links:

```
// Get the contents of the rich text box
                string rtbContents = new TextRange(rtbPaths.Document.ContentStart, rtbPaths.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
                foreach (string line in rtbContents.Split('\n'))
                {
                    String trimmedLine = line.Trim(' ', '\r');
                    if (trimmedLine.Length > 0)
                    {
                        // If the line is not empty, assume it's a valid url and add it to the files list
                        // Note: You could check if the url is valid before adding it, and probably should do this is a real application
                        downloader.Files.Add(new FileDownloader.FileInfo(trimmedLine));
                    }
                }
```

But i don't understand what richTextBox ? I guess it's in the design in the DownloaderDemo.xaml

Still if i want to add my own links to download files ?

This is DownloaderDemo.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace FileDownloaderApp
{
    /// <summary>Interaction logic for DownloaderDemo.xaml</summary>
    public partial class DownloaderDemo : Window
    {
        // Creating a new instance of a FileDownloader
        private FileDownloader downloader = new FileDownloader();

        public DownloaderDemo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close,
                new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args) { this.Close(); })));

            downloader.StateChanged += new EventHandler(downloader_StateChanged);
            downloader.CalculatingFileSize += new FileDownloader.CalculatingFileSizeEventHandler(downloader_CalculationFileSize);
            downloader.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler(downloader_ProgressChanged);
            downloader.FileDownloadAttempting += new EventHandler(downloader_FileDownloadAttempting);
            downloader.FileDownloadStarted += new EventHandler(downloader_FileDownloadStarted);
            downloader.Completed += new EventHandler(downloader_Completed);
            downloader.CancelRequested += new EventHandler(downloader_CancelRequested);
            downloader.DeletingFilesAfterCancel += new EventHandler(downloader_DeletingFilesAfterCancel);
            downloader.Canceled += new EventHandler(downloader_Canceled);

        }

        public void DragWindow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
        {
            DragMove();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Height -= 30;
        }

        // A simple implementation of setting the directory path, adding files from a textbox and starting the download
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog openFolderDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Set the path to the local directory where the files will be downloaded to
                downloader.LocalDirectory = openFolderDialog.SelectedPath;

                // Clear the current list of files (in case it's not the first download)
                downloader.Files.Clear();

                // Get the contents of the rich text box
                string rtbContents = new TextRange(rtbPaths.Document.ContentStart, rtbPaths.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
                foreach (string line in rtbContents.Split('\n'))
                {
                    String trimmedLine = line.Trim(' ', '\r');
                    if (trimmedLine.Length > 0)
                    {
                        // If the line is not empty, assume it's a valid url and add it to the files list
                        // Note: You could check if the url is valid before adding it, and probably should do this is a real application
                        downloader.Files.Add(new FileDownloader.FileInfo(trimmedLine));
                    }
                }

                // Start the downloader
                downloader.Start();
            }
        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Pause the downloader
            downloader.Pause();
        }

        private void btnResume_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Resume the downloader
            downloader.Resume();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Stop the downloader
            // Note: This will not be instantantanious - the current requests need to be closed down, and the downloaded files need to be deleted
            downloader.Stop();
        }

        // This event is fired every time the paused or busy state is changed, and used here to set the controls of the interface
        // This makes it enuivalent to a void handling both downloader.IsBusyChanged and downloader.IsPausedChanged
        private void downloader_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Setting the buttons
            btnStart.IsEnabled = downloader.CanStart;
            btnStop.IsEnabled = downloader.CanStop;
            btnPause.IsEnabled = downloader.CanPause;
            btnResume.IsEnabled = downloader.CanResume;

            // Enabling or disabling the setting controls
            rtbPaths.IsReadOnly = downloader.IsBusy;
            cbUseProgress.IsEnabled = !downloader.IsBusy;
        }

        // Show the progress of file size calculation
        // Note that these events will only occur when the total file size is calculated in advance, in other words when the SupportsProgress is set to true
        private void downloader_CalculationFileSize(object sender, Int32 fileNr)
        {
            lblStatus.Content = String.Format("Calculating file sizes - file {0} of {1}", fileNr, downloader.Files.Count);
        }

        // Occurs every time of block of data has been downloaded, and can be used to display the progress with
        // Note that you can also create a timer, and display the progress every certain interval
        // Also note that the progress properties return a size in bytes, which is not really user friendly to display
        //      The FileDownloader class provides static functions to format these byte amounts to a more readible format, either in binary or decimal notation 
        private void downloader_ProgressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pBarFileProgress.Value = downloader.CurrentFilePercentage();
            lblFileProgress.Content = String.Format("Downloaded {0} of {1} ({2}%)", FileDownloader.FormatSizeBinary(downloader.CurrentFileProgress), FileDownloader.FormatSizeBinary(downloader.CurrentFileSize), downloader.CurrentFilePercentage()) + String.Format(" - {0}/s", FileDownloader.FormatSizeBinary(downloader.DownloadSpeed));

            if (downloader.SupportsProgress)
            {
                pBarTotalProgress.Value = downloader.TotalPercentage();
                lblTotalProgress.Content = String.Format("Downloaded {0} of {1} ({2}%)", FileDownloader.FormatSizeBinary(downloader.TotalProgress), FileDownloader.FormatSizeBinary(downloader.TotalSize), downloader.TotalPercentage());
            }
        }

        // This will be shown when the request for the file is made, before the download starts (or fails)
        private void downloader_FileDownloadAttempting(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Content = String.Format("Preparing {0}", downloader.CurrentFile.Path);
        }

        // Display of the file info after the download started
        private void downloader_FileDownloadStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Content = String.Format("Downloading {0}", downloader.CurrentFile.Path);
            lblFileSize.Content = String.Format("File size: {0}", FileDownloader.FormatSizeBinary(downloader.CurrentFileSize));
            lblSavingTo.Content = String.Format("Saving to {0}\\{1}", downloader.LocalDirectory, downloader.CurrentFile.Name);
        }

        // Display of a completion message, showing the amount of files that has been downloaded.
        // Note, this does not hold into account any possible failed file downloads
        private void downloader_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Content = String.Format("Download complete, downloaded {0} files.", downloader.Files.Count);
        }

        // Show a message that the downloads are being canceled - all files downloaded will be deleted and the current ones will be aborted
        private void downloader_CancelRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Content = "Canceling downloads...";
        }

        // Show a message that the downloads are being canceled - all files downloaded will be deleted and the current ones will be aborted
        private void downloader_DeletingFilesAfterCancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Content = "Canceling downloads - deleting files...";
        }

        // Show a message saying the downloads have been canceled
        private void downloader_Canceled(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Content = "Download(s) canceled";
            pBarFileProgress.Value = 0;
            pBarTotalProgress.Value = 0;
            lblFileProgress.Content = "-";
            lblTotalProgress.Content = "-";
            lblFileSize.Content = "-";
            lblSavingTo.Content = "-";
        }

        // Setting the SupportsProgress property - if set to false, no total progress data will be avaible!
        private void cbUseProgress_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            downloader.SupportsProgress = (Boolean)cbUseProgress.IsChecked; 
        }

        // Setting the DeleteCompletedFilesAfterCancel property - indicates if the completed files should be deleted after cancellation
        private void cbDeleteCompletedFiles_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            downloader.DeleteCompletedFilesAfterCancel = (Boolean)cbDeleteCompletedFiles.IsChecked;
        }

        // Close the window when the close button is hit
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every second sentence in your post has a question mark at the end. None of them is a question ...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add to the rich text box new download links by creating your own function that takes a new download link path, to append to the text box you do:

```
richTextBox.AppendText("new string of download link");
```

You're not sure what rich text box? It is in your .xaml file, it is called rtbPaths. So you could create a new button that executes a dialog box, takes a string and use that string to append to this text box.

It's hard to understand what is being asked here as well, sorry if I got this wrong.

Comment: The question is how to add for example 100 links not only one ? I have a class where i create a List<string> with 100 links. How can i loop it by code and add the links to the richTextBox ? I have to do it only in the xaml file where the richTextBox is ? Or i can do it in the csharp code file using foreach or for ? But the question is how to add many links. I'm not sure how to work with the xaml.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of what mvvm is, I suggest you read about it more, it will alleviate your confusion. You will loop through each element of the list if you want and on each iteration use the AppendText() function that I mentioned. If you want to control how many are added at run time then pass in an integer to a function as value, that can control how many times to iterate. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx